# Print selected text on a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing, textarea

I need to print just the selected text from a textarea on an HTML page using javascript and not the entire webpage. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Edit: I used the solution on the following link along with windows.getSelection to access the selected text and it worked.

http://vikku.info/codesnippets/javascript/print-div-content-print-only-the-content-of-an-html-element-and-not-the-whole-document/

Comment: Can you post the code you're using as well as anything you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can only print a page of html.

What you probably need to use is media queries to hide the elements you do not want to print from the printer:

```
@media print {
    .no-print {
        display:none'
    }
}
```

Or you could use javascript to render the selected text as a new page and print that, but that would not necessarily be a good experience for a user.